# Creating parse trees in NLTK using tagged sentence

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, parse-tree

Using the methods defined in [the NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08), I want to create a parse tree of a sentence that has already been POS tagged. From what I understand from the chapter linked above, any words you want to be able to recognize need to be in the grammar. This seems ridiculous, seeing as there's a built in POS tagger that would make hand-writing the parts of speech for each word completely redundant. Am I missing some functionality of the parsing methods that allows for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different kinds of technology involved here. The chapter you link to is about hand-written context-free grammars, which typically have a few dozen rules and can handle a tiny subset of English (or any other language you cover). While it is possible to create a large-coverage system on a very large number of such rules (plus other technologies), the CFG implementation in the NLTK is only intended for teaching or demonstration purposes-- put differently, it's a toy. Don't even think about using it for general-purpose parsing.

For parsing real text, there are probabilistic parsers like the Stanford parser (for which the nltk has an interface in `nltk.parse.stanford`). Such parsers are generally trained on large treebanks, they can handle unknown words, and as you would expect they either take POS-tagged text as input, or do their own POS tagging.

All this said, it's not hard to tweak the NLTK's CFG machinery to handle unknown words, if you have reason to do that: Write grammars over POS tags rather than over words (e.g., you'd write `NP => "DT" "NN"`, so that the POS tags are the terminals); then extract the POS tags from your tagged sentence, build a parse tree over them, and put the words back in. (This won't be enough if your CFG contains rules that mix terminals and non-terminals, like `"give" NP "to" NP`.)

Comment: Any advice on how to install this and use this? I'm about at my wits end trying to get this to work

Comment: You mean advice on installing and using the Stanford tools? I'm not sure why or where you were stuck, but it seems you've managed with the help of @NathanMcCoy, right?

Comment: Yeah, @NathanMcCoy got me most of the way... If anyone else comes along looking for how to install, remember you have to change the JAVAHOME variable as well: `os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = '/path/to/java/home'`

Comment: Did you consult https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software when you tried to set it up?

Comment: I did, but I have no experience modifying the classpath, which was where I was having trouble

Answer (score 3):

With the stanford parser, POS tags are not needed to get a parse for a tree as it is built into the model. The `StanfordParser` and models are not available out of the box and need to be downloaded.

Most people see this error when trying to use the `StanfordParser` in NLTK

```
>>> from nltk.parse import stanford
>>> sp = stanford.StanfordParser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 51, in __init__
    key=lambda model_name: re.match(self._JAR, model_name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 714, in find_jar_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser\.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-parser\.jar, see:
    <http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml>
===========================================================================
```

To fix this, Download the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download) to a directory and extract the contents. Let's use the example directory on a *nix system `/usr/local/lib/stanfordparser`. The file `stanford-parser.jar` must be located there, along with the other files.

When all the files are there, set the environment variables for the location of the parser and models.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = '/usr/local/lib/stanfordparser'
>>> os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/usr/local/lib/stanfordparser'
```

Now you can use the parser to export the possible parses for the sentence you have, for example:

```
>>> sp = stanford.StanfordParser()
>>> sp.parse("this is a sentence".split())
<list_iterator object at 0x7f53b93a2dd8>
>>> trees = [tree for tree in sp.parse("this is a sentence".split())]
>>> trees[0] # example parsed sentence
Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['this'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['sentence'])])])])])
```

An `iterator` object is returned since there can be more than one parser for a given sentence.

Comment: This was very helpful with installing the parser! The only reason I don't choose best answer is because it doesn't explain the main part of my question, it simply helps to install the parser

Comment: To get the results out of an iterator, just write `trees = list(sp.parse("this is a sentence".split()))`

Comment: @bendl I saw your comment on the other answer and inferred you were more interested in installing and using the `StanfordParser` which is not obvious at first. Glad I could help.